# Counting how many times variable has changed

Tags: c++

I have to write the program, when after terminating infinite while loop "while(cin>>a)" by, let's say "-1", program says me how many times value increased. For input "0 0 2 2 3 4 8 8 8 -1" it should print "4". First part isn't problem, but I have no idea how to count how many times it had changed over time. Any tips? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about the following `1 2 3 1 2 3`?

Comment: Did you try something yet?

Comment: Numbers have to be wrote in ascending order.

Comment: Loop body would look like this: `{ if (a == -1) break; if (a > last) ++count; last = a; }`

Comment: Please phrase you question clearly.

Comment: Sorry, english isn't my first, or even second language. Program should write out, how many times value increased.

Comment: Create a class that contains the variable as a private member. Add a public set function which updates the variable, and add a counter to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use counters which will basically increase each time your value increases. Check the code bellow:

```
int value, highestValue, counter = 0, counter2 = 0;
do{
       cout << "Enter the value: ";
       cin >> value;
       if(counter2 == 0){
                    highestValue = value;
                  }
       if(value > highestValue){
                  counter++;
                  highestValue = value;
                }
       counter2++;
}while(value != -1);

cout << "The number increased " << counter << " times!\n";
```

The second counter (counter2) is required in the first if statement to store the first value you enter as the highest value.

Comment: Actually, you could just initialise highestValue to std::numeric_limits<int>::min() and remove counter2 all references to it.

Answer (score -1):

```
int p = -1, k, a, b;
while( cin >> a )                                                //infinite loop
 { 
   if ( k != a )
      p++;
   b = a - k;
   if(a=-1)
    exit(0);
   k = a;
  }
cout << "value increased by" << b;
cout << "number of times it has changed over time = " << p;
```

Comment: Care to explain your solution?